# Classloader loading wrong log.properties file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, classloader

I have EAR which contains multiple jars out of which two of the jar contains "log.properties"

For eg: In abc.jar, "log.properties"  is in com.abc.test
and in xyz.jar, "log.properties"  is in com.xyz.test

In both the package we have logger implementation which load "log.properties" as 
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log.properties");

Due to classloader which loads the other jar first it pickup his "log.properties"

I want to avoid this problem
Any suggestions ?

Comment: not possible to change the properties file name?

Comment: Nope, as it is already deployed on server. and log implementer is used by most of the modules

Answer (score 1):

Use [ClassLoader.getResources(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources%28java.lang.String%29) and write code to filter out URLs that are not in the same package as the class.  Place that code in a utility or resource manager class and use it everywhere in your project.